# Is there a way to call the method of a WinForms program running and to set parameters for the method from another WinForms program?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to call the method of a program (Winforms) running and to set parameters for the method from another program (Winforms)? C#
Everyone can share it with me.

Thank you everyone !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called [inter process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

As from Wikipedia, pick the one that's most convenient for you:

- File / Registry
- Windows Messages
- Message Queuing
- Sockets
- Pipes
- Shared Memory

---

As for windows, you can use COM/ATL as well, but that might be a bit overkill.

Comment: Is there a specific case for you?
Is it possible to load the dll or exe file to do the above?

Comment: If you want to be independent,  COM might be a way to do it. Here's a starting point: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/612604/Best-Practice-in-Writing-a-COM-Visible-Assembly-Cs